# dojo List input, with each item having two values

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have created a dojo list input [ListInput](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/form/ListInput.html))

i have  a requirement, in which each item added to the list should have a display value and a value.
just like we have in dijit.form.FilteringSelect .
I am showing the displa yvalue to user (say name) but internally i need to populate values(say ID).

The ListInput's add method accepts a string and creates an Item to the List.
I would like to add a value as a pair like

```
{name:"Apple",id:"1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a way to do this other than editing/re-creating the dojo - provided source file.

so as a trick i added a hidden input field with all the `items` and collected these values at the servlet. which is working fine as of now.

Any better  idea is appreciated.